# React Native IOS Navigation Stack Event Listeners

Tags: ios, react-native

Let's assume you are on a twitter-like application. You are viewing a specific news feed. From that news feed you can link to profiles. Those profiles also have links to other profiles. Eventually you can click back to reach your original destination. (cyclical links)

In react native, I have a navigator pushing profiles components onto the navigation stack. However, each profile component has a series of event listeners to manage the updating of the views when the stores get updated, keyboard controls, etc...

If I continue to push components on to the stack without deallocating the memory to the old components, I will eventually run out of memory. Contrary to that, If I unmount the components or stop the event listeners any updates made several views deep will not be propagated to the rest of the application (I like a post several levels deep, but the post exists higher up in the stack).

How is this situation handled?